# How to get the 3 highest values in a HashMap?

Tags: java, sorting, hashmap, entryset

I have a hashmap which is the following:

```
    HashMap<String, Integer> hm = new HashMap<String, Integer>;
    hm.put("a", 1);
    hm.put("b", 12);
    hm.put("c", 53);
    hm.put("d", 2);
    hm.put("e", 17);
    hm.put("f", 8);
    hm.put("g", 8);
```

How would I get the keys which have the 3 highest values? So it would return:

```
    "c", "e", "b"
```

Thanks.

Comment: find the max value, remove and repeat twice?

Comment: Iterate over the value set in a for-loop.

Comment: If you want ordering you shouldn't be using a hash map in the first place. Use an ordered map such as `TreeMap`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

My solution, sort by values and get top 3 and return key list.

```java
List<String> keys = hm.entrySet().stream().sorted(Map.Entry.<String, Integer>comparingByValue().reversed()).limit(3).map(Map.Entry::getKey).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Hope it helps

Comment: That would work well for relatively small input maps (< 10000 elements).  It would be better to use some sort of collector that would keep track of the current top three, so that you don't have to sort the entire map.

Comment: @Daniel [here you go](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62078310/1059372)

Answer (score 4):

This is a lot harder to read, but will perform a lot better:

```
 public static List<String> firstN(Map<String, Integer> map, int n) {
    PriorityQueue<Entry<String, Integer>> pq = new PriorityQueue<>(
        n + 1, Map.Entry.comparingByValue()
    );

    int bound = n + 1;
    for (Entry<String, Integer> en : map.entrySet()) {
        pq.offer(en);
        if (pq.size() == bound) {
            pq.poll();
        }
    }

    int i = n;
    String[] array = new String[n];
    while (--i >= 0) {
        array[i] = pq.remove().getKey();
    }
    return Arrays.asList(array);
}
```

If you know how a `PriorityQueue` works, this is rather trivial: it keeps only `n + 1` elements at any given point in time. As elements are being added, the smallest element is removed, one by one.

When this is done, we insert elements into an array, but in reverse order (because a `PriorityQueue` keeps sorted only its head or the head is always max/min according to the `Comparator`).

You can even make this generic, or create a custom collector with streams for this.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my take on it:  This keeps track of only the top n items in a TreeSet.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class TopN {
    public static <E> Collection<E> topN(Iterable<E> values, Comparator<? super E> comparator, int n) {
        NavigableSet<E> result = new TreeSet<>(comparator.reversed());
        for (E value : values) {
            result.add(value);
            if (result.size() > n) {
                result.remove(result.last());
            }
        }
        return result;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<String, Integer> hm = Map.of(
                "a", 1,
                "b", 12,
                "c", 53,
                "d", 2,
                "e", 17,
                "f", 8,
                "g", 8);

        List<String> result = topN(hm.entrySet(), Map.Entry.comparingByValue(), 3)
                .stream()
                .map(Map.Entry::getKey)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
        System.out.println(result);
    }
}
```

The final output is `[c, e, b]`